# Creating a conditional table

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I'm trying to create a conditional table. 
Let's say I want to have such result: {1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0}.

The idea is to create a table of n elements (10 in a given example), but when one element
takes a specific value (5 in my example), then all of the remaining elements must take provided value (let's say zero).

It's important not to use IF checking every element whether it satisfies provided condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

> It's important not to use IF checking every element whether it satisfies provided condition.

I cannot agree with this, unless you mean that once the sought element is found the *rest* of the elements should not be checked (possibly) using `If`.  What I mean is that even if not using `If` itself there is going to be some kind of by-element checking until the target value is found.

One approach to what I believe you want:

```
SeedRandom[0]
a = RandomInteger[9, 10]
```

> ```
> {7, 0, 8, 2, 1, 5, 8, 0, 6, 7}
> ```

```
p = FirstPosition[a, 5][[1]]

Join[Take[a, p], ConstantArray[0, Length@a - p]]
```

> ```
> {7, 0, 8, 2, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Or more concise but less efficient:

```
Join[Take[a, p], 0 Drop[a, p]]
```

> ```
> {7, 0, 8, 2, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

---

### Update

Based on your comments I believe this should be of use to you:

```
cTable[f_, n_] := FoldList[If[# == 0, 0, f @ #2] &, f @ 1, 2 ~Range~ n]
```

Example:

```
f = Mod[2 # + 1, 9] &;

cTable[f, 10]
```

> ```
> {3, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Note that `f` is only called four times here, *not* once for each element in the output.  As proof we can add a [`Pause`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pause.html) to it:

```
f = (Pause[1]; Mod[2 # + 1, 9]) &;

cTable[f, 10] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {4.010006, {3, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

Because `FoldList` auto-compiles (by default for lists 100 or longer) this method should be acceptably fast.  For example a list with nearly 5,000,000 zeros takes only a fraction of a second on my machine:

```
cTable[Mod[2 # + 1, 9] &, 5000000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.360001, Null}
> ```

Comment: Yes, it's important not to check every element. I'm trying to create such table: Table[f[i],[i,1,N]]. The function f[i] is complicated and it takes long time to calculate it's value. However I know that if it takes the first value 0 as "i" varies from 1 to N, then the next values of it is also zero.
If f[3]=0, then the result should be {f[1],f[2],0,..,0} - N elments in the list.

Comment: Also important that I'm not creating list from a list.

Comment: @Fan please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is a more general pattern solution that doesn't require each value after five to be larger than five:

```
list = {9, 4, 9, 1, 2, 9, 5, 4, 4, 6};
list /. {a___, 5, b___} :> {a, 5, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[0, Length@{b}]}
(* Out: {9, 4, 9, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: this seems to most accurately implement what the text describes +1

Comment: @Artes The way I see it it's the only solution.

Comment: Let's say we do so: Table[f[i],{i,1,10}], with some given function f. It might be Sin[i], Cos[i] and etc. I want to do so: if f[i]=0, then f[i+1],..,f[10]=0. Not checking whether f[i+1],..,f[10]=0.
If, for example, f[1]>0, f[2]>0, but f[3]=0, then the result should be {f[1],f[2],0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}.

Comment: @Pickett Ok I provided another solution.

Comment: @FancierofMathematica With this solution you can do that, and also with the new solution by Artes.

Comment: @Artes Nice, +1

Answer (score 5):

The simplest code I can think of is:

```
Range@10 /. (x_ /; x > 5 :> 0)
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Comment: Thank You. It's simple when you know :)

Answer (score 5):

This solves the problem  as it has been  posed:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 11, 5, 3, 5, 9};

Join[ TakeWhile[ list, # != 5 &], {5}, 
      ConstantArray[0, Length[list] - FirstPosition[ list, 5]]]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 11, 5, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

In case the list consitst of consecutive elements:

```
Range @ 10 // # UnitStep[5 - #]&
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

If we are to find larger values we can use `Threashold`

```
Threshold[ Range @ 10, {"LargestValues", 5}]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

Comment: ... or `Threshold[Range[10], {"Hard", 5}]`. Pity that `Treshhold` doesn't find smallest values. Anyway, +1

Comment: @eldo Thanks, it seems the OP asked for something else, thus I updated the anser.

Comment: I haven't benchmarked it but it looks costly to evaluate both `FirstPosition` and `TakeWhile`, another option: `With[{fp = First@FirstPosition[list, 5]}, 
 Join[list[[1 ;; fp]], ConstantArray[0, Length@list - fp]]]`

Comment: Perhaps `TakeWhile[list, # != 5 &] // 
 Join[#, {5}, ConstantArray[0, Length@list - Length@# - 1]] &` so that `list` is not crawled twice.

Comment: `Clear[f1, f2, listTest];
listTest = Range[1, 10, 0.0001];
f1[list_, n_] := 
  Join[TakeWhile[list, # != n &], {n}, 
     ConstantArray[0, Length[list - FirstPosition[list, n]]]] // 
    AbsoluteTiming // First;
f2[list_, n_] := 
  TakeWhile[list, # != n &] // 
     Join[#, {n}, ConstantArray[0, Length@list - Length@# - 1]] & // 
    AbsoluteTiming // First;
Mean@Table[#[listTest, 5] & /@ {f1, f2}, {10}]` [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i0vr6.png)

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4];
list = {1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 11, 5, 3, 5, 9};

SetAttributes[f1, {Listable}]
(* redefine f1 to 0& when an input with value t is processed: *)
f1[t_, x_] := Piecewise[{{f1 = 0 &; x, x == t}}, x] 
f1[5 , list]
(* {1,2,3,7,9,11,5,0,0,0} *)

f2 = MapAt[0 &, #2, {1 + Position[#2, #1, 1, 1][[1, 1]] ;;}] &;
f2[5, list]
(* {1,2,3,7,9,11,5,0,0,0} *)

f3 = Function[{t, lst}, 
      Module[{ca = ConstantArray[0, {Length@lst}], 
        lw = ;; 1 + LengthWhile[lst, # != t &]}, ca[[lw]] = lst[[lw]]; ca]];
f3[5, list]
(* {1,2,3,7,9,11,5,0,0,0} *)

f4 = Function[{t, lst}, Module[{splt = Split[lst, # != t &]}, 
            splt[[2 ;;]] = 0 splt[[2 ;;]]; Join @@ splt]];
f4[5, list]
(* {1,2,3,7,9,11,5,0,0,0} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = Range[10];
```

**1.**

I think the operator form of `MapAt` with `Span` syntax wasn't available at the time the question was posed.

```
MapAt[0 &, 6 ;;] @ list
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

**2.1**

V 13.1 introduced `ReplaceAt`

```
ReplaceAt[list, _ :> 0, 6 ;;]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

**2.2**

`ReplaceAt` has the advantage that we can easily impose conditions:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "a", "b", 9, 10};

ReplaceAt[list, _?NumericQ :> 0, 6 ;;]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, "a", "b", 0, 0}

Answer (score 1):

**Using `MapIndexed`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 20]
```

> {2, 5, 1, 8, 1, 1, 9, 7, 1, 5, 2, 9, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 7}

```
condTable[k_List, n_, repl_ : 0] :=
 MapIndexed[
  If[First@#2 > First@FirstPosition[k, n, {Length@k}], repl, #] &, k
  ]
```

*Usage:*

```
condTable[list, 55, x]   (* not in list case *)
```

> {2, 5, 1, 8, 1, 1, 9, 7, 1, 5, 2, 9, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 7}

```
condTable[list, 4, x]
```

> {2, 5, 1, 8, 1, 1, 9, 7, 1, 5, 2, 9, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, x, x, x}

```
condTable[list, 9, g]
```

> {2, 5, 1, 8, 1, 1, 9, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g}

```
condTable[list, 7]      (* default case *)
```

> {2, 5, 1, 8, 1, 1, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

---

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 20];
condTableSeqRep[k_List, n_, repl_ : 0] :=
 SequenceReplace[k, {
   {a___Except[n] ..} :>  {a}
   , {a___, n, b___} :> 
    Sequence @@ {a, n, Sequence @@ Table[repl, Length@{b}]}
   }
  ]

condTableSeqRep[list, 55, x]    (* not in list case *)
condTableSeqRep[list, 4, x]
condTableSeqRep[list, 9, g]
condTableSeqRep[list, 7]        (* default case *)
```

---

> (* same results *)

Answer (score 0):

```
f[n_/;n >5]:=0
f[n_]:= n

Table[f[i],{i,1,10}]

(* {1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0} *)
```