# Replace missing data

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm

I have vectors of equal lengths where I want to replace the zeroes (missing data) with their preceding values. So far I have written:

```
dt = {1, 0, 2, 0, 3};

MapThread[(dt[[#1]] = dt[[#2]]) &, {#, #-1}] & [Position[dt, 0]];

dt
```

> {1, 1, 2, 2, 3}

I have 3 questions:

(1) Are there alternatives to the above code, which I don't like aesthetically ?

(2) How can I expand it to go over matrices of equal-length-vectors ?

(3) How can I deal with a zero in the first position (replace by the following element) ?

Comment: Should multiple zeros in a row all be replaced, e.g. {2, 0, 0, 7} -> {2, 2, 2, 7}?

Comment: Yes. The problem seems familiar to me too. Wasn't able to locate it.

Comment: Related: [(26723)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26723/121).  Somewhat related: [(57526)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57526/121)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(2952)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2952/121)

Comment: What if the first element is zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is a duplicate but since I failed to find it with ten minutes of searching:

```
x = {2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1};

FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #, #2] &, x]
```

> ```
> {2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1}
> ```

To handle leading zeros:

```
x = {0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1};

FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #, #2] &, SelectFirst[x, # != 0 &], Rest @ x]
```

> ```
> {7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1}
> ```

The case without leading zeroes can also be handled nicely using `Split`, borrowed from Leonid's method for [Fill out blanks with a upcoming number in a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2952/121):

```
x = {2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1};

Join @@ Accumulate /@ Split[x, #2 == 0 &]
```

> ```
> {2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1}
> ```

The leading zeros can be handled by prepending the first non-zero value to the list, then applying `Rest` at the end.

For Q2 I think all you need is to convert either method to a function and map it:

```
fn[x_] := FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #, #2] &, SelectFirst[x, # != 0 &], Rest @ x]

fn /@ {{2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1}}
```

> ```
> {{2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Phantastic !!! How would you map it over matrices ? (Q2)

Comment: @eldo Would you please provide an example?

Comment: --------------{x,x}

Comment: @eldo Sorry, I still don't understand.

Comment: Dear Wizard, my real situation is like this: x = {{2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1}}

Comment: @eldo And what output do you want?

Comment: {{2,2,2, 7,7, 3, 3, 3,1, {1, 1, 2, 7,7, 3, 3, 3, 1}}

Comment: @eldo Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

### TemporalData + MissingDataMethod

```
ClearAll[interpolateMissing]
interpolateMissing = Quiet @ TemporalData[# /. 0 -> Missing[], Automatic, 
  MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}]["States"] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
interpolateMissing  @ {1, 0, 2, 0, 3}
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 2, 3}}

```
interpolateMissing  @ {0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1}
```

> {{7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1}}

```
interpolateMissing  @ {0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1}
```

> {{7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1}}

At the price of extra pair braces in the output when the input is a list, we get the second requirement

> ***How can I expand it to go over matrices of equal-length-vectors?***

for free, since `interpolateMissing` works as is when the input is an array:

```
interpolateMissing  @ {{1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1}, {0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1}}
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1}, {7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1}}

**Note:** `Quiet` is used to suppress the following warning:

> *InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. **Extrapolation** will be used. >>*

By the way, `Extrapolation` is exactly what we need to handle cases with leading zeros according to requirement (3).

Comment: Maybe "replaceMissing" should be "interpolateMissing"?

Comment: @Rabbit, yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use repeated replacement 
1,3) The first two rules handle leading zeros, the first one handles several leading zeros and the second one handles a single leading zero.:

```
cleanVector[v_]:=v//.{ {0, x:0___,y_,z___}:>{y,x,y,z},
                       {0, x:0...,y_,z___}:>{y,x,y,z},
                       {x___,y_,0,z___} :> {x,y,y,z} };
```

2) Depending on what you mean by 'go over matrices' I'd just map this over the matrix to clean each vector independently.

```
m={v1,v2,v3};
cleanVector/@m;
```